# Call POST request call using C#. Convert PowerShell code to CSharp code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

How can I convert this one line PowerShell code to C# code

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri 'https://s16events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=sdnfgknsdkfglkshnklsdfhgoihohsndfgndfgknkkdfg'

I'm using Visual Studio to do this

Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpClient`:

```
// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main()
{
  // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
  try   
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://s16events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=sdnfgknsdkfglkshnklsdfhgoihohsndfgndfgknkkdfg", new StringContent(requestBody));

     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }  
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");  
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
}
```

Example adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8